# Calling CMD commands sequentially (WLST Python Scripts)

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, wlst

I know there are many questions around sequentially calling shell commands from a batch file. However, I am unable to get through this peculiar issue, mainly while calling Oracle WebLogic (WLST) Python scripts.

I have a batch file, which at a high level does these things:

1. Copies some files to their designated location
2. Starts Oracle WebLogic server
3. Calls `script1.py` to configure something on Admin Server
4. Calls some other shell commands
5. Calls `script2.py` to configure something else on Admin Server

Snippet from the file:

```
:: set some paths
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN (config.properties) DO (set %%G=%%H) 

:: copy files
call copyFiles.bat

:: start the server
start startWebLogic.cmd

:: execute script 1
set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:MaxHeapSize=512m"
%WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd script-1.py

:: some more DOS commands

:: execute script 2 
%WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd script-2.py
```

The problem is in steps 3 and 5. Whenever `wlst` initializes and starts execution, it owns the console and starts printing the output on the console. Once done, it won't execute the next script commands at all. The execution simply stops then and there. The control just ends inside `%WLST_PATH%`.

As a workaround, I am using `start` and `timeout` commands.

```
:: execute script 1
set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:MaxHeapSize=512m"
start /MIN wlst.cmd %WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd script-1.py
timeout /t 40 /nobreak

:: some more DOS commands

:: execute script 2 
start /MIN wlst.cmd %WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd script-2.py
timeout /t 40 /nobreak
```

I have also tried using `call` but it didn't help, and it results in the same problem as mentioned above. Is there a better way to do it? What I want is that all these commands should get executed in sequence.

Comment: Try `cmd /c ""%WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd" script-1.py"`. That will run wlst.cmd in a new shell attached to the same console, which will wait for it to exit before returning control to the parent shell.

Comment: Your code can not reach step 3. In step 2 you are transfering execution flow to `startWebLogic.cmd`. Try with `start startWebLogic.cmd`

Comment: @eryksun Perfect! You may add it as an answer.

Comment: @MCND You are right. It's actually as you have mentioned. I have edited my question.

Comment: Now you only need to do with `wlst.cmd` the same you are doing with `copyfiles.bat`, that is, `call "%WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd" script-1.py`

Comment: Does saying it's "actually as you have mentioned" mean it was a typo in the question? Or did using `start startWebLogic.cmd` allow a subsequent `call` to work as expected?

Comment: @eryksun It was a typo in the question on the line `start startWebLogic.cmd`. However, that is not the issue, I can still live with that. The actual issue is while calling `script-1.py` and `script-2.py`. For this, I have used the approach you suggested in your first comment.

Comment: Ok, I thought that maybe @MCND had solved the problem. As is it's still a mystery why `call "%WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd" script-1.py` isn't returning control. Using `cmd /c` is a workaround, but not an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **eryksun**, this issue was resolved by using:

```
cmd /c ""%WLST_PATH%\wlst.cmd" script-1.py"
```